# Comment disappeared

Tags: support, comment, deletion, auto-delete

In the following question: [Are there any irrational/transcendental numbers for which the distribution of decimal digits is not uniform?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195581/are-there-any-irrational-transcendental-numbers-for-which-the-distribution-of-de), I distinctly remember adding a comment about "God being lazy and tossing dies to generate important irrational numbers". When I visit the question now, I can no longer find that comment. I don't even see any notification saying it was removed. I swear I saw it just a few hours ago. Can comments be removed from questions without notice?

Comment: Moderators have the power to delete comments without any notice.

Comment: You can find some basic details on deletion of comments in the section "Who can delete comments?" of the FAQ post [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)

Comment: And also, since that's not really [the purpose of comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), it's rightly deleted.

Comment: This comment was deleted by a moderator. It wasn't me, but if I had seen this comment I would also have deleted it.

Comment: @davidlowryduda may I ask why? I want to avoid offending in the future, so curious if it was because God was referenced perhaps? To me, it seemed clear it was only a joke.

Comment: @AndrewT. I don't mind it getting deleted, but nothing in your link suggests one can't crack the odd joke. There are many instances of this throughout the site and in my opinion adds to the richness of the conversation (even if some of them aren't very funny).

Comment: It's true that there are many similar comments on the site. It's also true that many similar comments get deleted all the time. You can make playful remarks as long as it's not excessive (in volume and in form). Just be prepared that they might get deleted. To be clear,  I think no one has an actual problem with this comment specifically;  it's just that such comments routinely get deleted.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, comments are often removed by moderators without notice, often in response to a flag on the comment by some user. Indeed, this is one of the main activities of moderators.

Many of these removal are also harmless. The reason for removal is merely that the comment is not (or not anymore) necessary, at some point this was called "too chatty" it now became "no longer needed." (Of course, we also remove rude comments. But the point I want to make is that this is not the only reason, and in fact not the most common one.)

This is what happened in the current case.

Answer (score 0):

Since comments are ephemeral, I've putting my opinions into an answer.  As many users notice, moderators can remove any comments without prior notice.  Nonetheless, it would be better to suggest some of the possible reasons that your comments get deleted.

As the name "Math Stack *Exchange*" suggests, we communicate in math on the main site, so it's important to keep the site *focused on math*.  To avoid an overflow of comments which doesn't help understanding the problem, those comments should be cleared.

Your comment *doesn't* make sense for atheists, who *don't* believe in *existence* of God.  Since posts here are supposed to be neutral in religious belief, I don't think that's a suitable comment on this site.

Comment: While it is true that generally we try to steer clear of the religious, political, etc. I think for the specific case this is mostly tangential; the main rational for me in favor of deleting it is that it's a light-hearted comment that did not add anything substantial. (I should maybe add that It was not I that deleted it. But that's my take on this.)

Comment: It was only a joke, but sure.